# How can I get this PHP code to send emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

### EDIT: Turns out that my problem was caused by hackers flooding my email server and that is why I wasn't receiving emails. I inserted a captcha on my form and it began working.

I have a website that uses a custom php file to submit email leads.

When someone fills out the contact form, it shows the success message, but the email never arrives in my inbox.

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="php/send_form_email.php">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="first_name">First Name<br>
            <input type="text" class="llonger" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="John">
        </label>
        <label for="last_name">Last Name<br>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Smith">
        </label>
        <label for="email">Email Address<br>
            <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="my@email.com">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitlonger">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**This is the PHP code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "email@website.com";
    $email_subject = "Contact Submission";
    function died($error) {
       echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo $error;
        die();
    }
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
 
    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Remove the error suppressor operator `@` from the `mail()` function and check its return value.

Comment: Never use the `@` before a function call.  This tells it to hide errors.  You *want* to see errors so you can fix/handle them.

Comment: @jeroen, I figured out what you mean. I removed the "@" in the following - @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

However, after another test it still doesn't work.

Comment: @warnakey: It means do `mail(...)` instead of `@mail(...)`.  Get rid of the `@` before `mail()`.  See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: @warnakey `mail()` returns `true` or `false` (in case of a failure). `true` means the problem is not with the php but somewhere after that (the mail server, etc.).

Comment: @jeroen. I will try having the success email go to another mail server to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @jeroen. I just tried switching out the email_to to an address I am certain would work (I use the exact same code successfully for another site) but it showed the success message again, but I never received an email. I think there is something wrong with my PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need to wrap your mail function in a conditional...

```
if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
  //display success...
}else{
  //display fail...
}
```

this will suppress the erroneous 'success message'..

the mail function returns true/false but true doesn't necessarily mean it worked if it returned true...
see here... http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

also, if it were me I'd remove the "@" at the begining of the mail function, so that you can catch any possible syntax, or other errors that may be preventing it from working...

Edit: in context example...

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){ 
 ?>
  <!-- include your own success html here -->
  Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
 <?php
}else{
 ?>
  <!-- fail html -->
  Email could not be sent...
 <?php
}
```

EDIT2: pure php...

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){ 
  echo 'Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.';
}else{
  echo 'Email could not be sent...';
}
```

Comment: I tried adding in  your code exactly the way you wrote it, but it didn't work. Maybe you forgot a ;.
Can you try posting your code in context with the rest of the code?

Comment: sure thing! but first, what exactly do you mean by 'doesn't work'??

Comment: Sorry, by "doesn't work" I mean that after hitting the submit button a white screen appears with no text in it. Where as usually, a white screen appears with the words " Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon. "

Comment: @warnakey: Try to add this to the top of your page: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`.

Comment: ahh, yeah, you have to provide some fail text... see the edit..

Comment: @RocketHazmat hey there, when you say "top of your page" - are you referring to the PHP file, or the HTML file? Because, you can't set something above <?php (on a php file) or above <!doctype html> (on an html file). Could you be more specific about what page you mean and where EXACTLY I should place that code?

Comment: if the function is just returning false, and you see no errors after turning error reporting on, as suggested by @Rocket... then it's likely your mail server that's failing...which will likely happen if you are doing this in a local hosting environment, I've never had much luck getting email functions to work on local development server..(xxamp, etc..)

Comment: @warnakey: Right after the 1st `<?php`.

Comment: Hey @jsuna. I copied in the text exactly how you made it and I still see a white screen with no text on it after I hit submit.

Comment: @jsuna: I didn't see your original answer, so I assumed "white screen" meant there was an error, not that he didn't put something in the `else`.

Comment: error reporting goes at the top of your php file, after the opening <?php tag...
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
//rest of php/html below...

Comment: @Rocket.. yeah could be caused by an error, it looks like the error reporting may not be set up correctly..

Comment: @warnakey - hmm, yeah need to get your error reporting up and working..

Comment: I am confused now because RocketHazmat pasted this code `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`, but jsuna posted this code `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Which one should I actually post?

Comment: @warnakey also I notice you are testing if $_POST variables are isset() and unless they are checkboxes or radios will return true even if the fields are empty... need to change those to !empty()..

Comment: also @jsuna, are you sure your example code is correct? Isn't it supposed to end with `?>`. Yet you have yours ending with `<?php
}`. Can you clarify?

Comment: I would use E_ALL ... http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

not sure what -1 would do, may work with both

Comment: @warnakey - what you are seeing is mixing php with html...you need to end the php bit with ?> then start it again before the closing bracket just after the html part

Comment: Hey @jsuna. I actually modified this PHP from a very simple example. Can you tell me which variables need to be changed and how to change the @_POST variables to !empty(). This is totally over my head and I don't really understand the difference.

Comment: @warnakey - this is getting too long, hit me up in skype and I'll hook you up.. jays.ink